# Dynamically create the "KEEP" List in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a keep list dynamically. Say:

```
%MACRO TEST(A=,B=,OUT_VAR=,KEEP_VAR=);
&OUT_VAR=MAX(&A,&B);
%IF &KEEP_VAR = 'Y' %THEN VAR_LIST=%SYSFUNC(CATS(VAR_LIST,&OUT_VAR));
%PUT VAR_LIST;
%MEND;

DATA ABC (keep = VAR_LIST);
LENGTH VAR_LIST $100.;
RETAIN VAR_LIST '';
%TEST(A=1,B=3,OUT_VAR=FIRS,KEEP_VAR='Y');
%TEST(A=2,B=4,OUT_VAR=SEC,KEEP_VAR='Y');
%TEST(A=3,B=5,OUT_VAR=THIR,KEEP_VAR='N');
RUN;
```

I have a datastep in which i am creating several variables calculated by the macro code.
I want to create a dynamic list of these output variables and then use it in the keep statement.
The above code does not seem to work, can someone suggest what am I missing here.

Comment: What do you want your output dataset to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A running data step is source code that has already been compiled.  You are trying to change the source while it is running -- that is not going to happen.  This is a symptom of mixing scopes and contexts between macro code and generated code.

However, the `TEST` macro is generating source and thus can either

- maintain state information for generating a `KEEP` source code statement after the macros are invoked.
- generate an additional `KEEP` statement per `TEST` invocation

In general, macro only parameter values are already 'strings', and do not need to be quoted.

```
%MACRO TEST(A=,B=,OUT_VAR=,KEEP_VAR=);
  &OUT_VAR=MAX(&A,&B);/* generates data step source code*/
  %IF &KEEP_VAR = 'Y' %THEN
    %LET VAR_LIST=&VARLIST &OUT_VAR;
%MEND;

* must occur before sequence of TEST invocations;
%global VARLIST; * globals generally want to be avoided, next version avoids it;
%let VARLIST =;

DATA ABC;
%TEST(A=1,B=3,OUT_VAR=FIRS,KEEP_VAR='Y');
%TEST(A=2,B=4,OUT_VAR=SEC,KEEP_VAR='Y');
%TEST(A=3,B=5,OUT_VAR=THIR,KEEP_VAR='N');
KEEP &VARLIST;
RUN;

%symdel VARLIST;
```

I hope this is a learning exercise -- The above pattern of coding has a macro generate code that would suffice as two normal non-macro data step statements do.  Too much macroification can be obfuscating.

Additionally, the output `ABC` might not be what you expect.  There will be **one** row with A=3, B=5, FIRS=4, SEC=6 and no THIR=8. So you have also some mixed up row and column data concepts.

Here is a cleaner alternative in which `TEST` generates the `KEEP`

```
%MACRO TEST(A=,B=,OUT_VAR=,KEEP_VAR=);
  &OUT_VAR=MAX(&A,&B);/* generates data step source code*/
  %IF %upcase(&KEEP_VAR) = Y %THEN %STR(KEEP &OUT_VAR;);
%MEND;

DATA ABC;
  %TEST(A=1,B=3,OUT_VAR=FIRS,KEEP_VAR=Y);
  %TEST(A=2,B=4,OUT_VAR=SEC,KEEP_VAR=Y);
  %TEST(A=3,B=5,OUT_VAR=THIR,KEEP_VAR=N);      
RUN;
```

The macro code still has to rely on the caller to specify a proper `KEEP_VAR` parameter Y or not Y.

An alternative is to push the Y/N KEEP concept into two parameters, use of one parameter over the other discriminates the KEEP.

```
%MACRO TEST(A=,B=,KEEP_VAR=,TEMP_VAR=);
  %IF %length (&KEEP_VAR) %then %do;
    &KEEP_VAR 
  %end;
  %else %do;
    &TEMP_VAR
  %end;

  MAX(&A,&B);

  %IF %length (&KEEP_VAR) %then %do;
    KEEP &KEEP_VAR;
  %end;
%MEND;

DATA ABC;
  %TEST(A=1,B=3,KEEP_VAR=FIRS);
  %TEST(A=2,B=4,KEEP_VAR=SEC);
  %TEST(A=3,B=5,TEMP_VAR=THIR);
RUN;
```

For me, a widely used macro should have clarity of invocation.  The black box of the macro implementation can strive to be as clean and efficient but does not have to be.

Comment: It worked perfectly, I just tweaked it a bit per my needs. Also, is there a way to create a var (say keep_var_list) in macro's body and instead of doing a keep statement individually for each variable, we keep concatenating the variable's name to keep_var_list and then pass this back to the datastep? That is what I was trying to achieve intially, thanks

Comment: What you were trying to achieve initially can't be done.  The first example has `%IF &KEEP_VAR = 'Y' %THEN %LET VAR_LIST=&VARLIST &OUT_VAR;
` to accumulate a variable list in a global macro variable.  A running data step can not change what the output columns are.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to do, but you can use multiple `KEEP` statements if want.

```
data want ;
   x=1;
   keep x;
   y=2;
   z=3;
   keep z;
run;
```

Although for your application it looks like you might want to generate a `DROP` statement instead.

```
%MACRO TEST(A=,B=,OUT_VAR=,KEEP_VAR=Y);
  &OUT_VAR=MAX(&A,&B);
%IF (&KEEP_VAR ^= Y) %THEN %DO;
  drop &out_var ;
%end;
%MEND;

DATA ABC ;
  %TEST(A=1,B=3,OUT_VAR=FIRST)
  %TEST(A=2,B=4,OUT_VAR=SECOND)
  %TEST(A=3,B=5,OUT_VAR=THIRD,KEEP_VAR=N)
RUN;
```